# Why is it important to have Core DB in Content Delivery Environment if i have static content sites?

Tags: sitecore-client, sql-database

What is the significance of having core database in CD Environment and which are all tables  being used from CD Environment?

Do we really need core DB for the below scenario?

Sites are only marketing sites, no login is required and no tracking of anonymous visitor.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/core-database.html

As per the above link ,`core` db handles personal data and this is something is not required in my scenario.

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/5390

The above forum  states if at all if we use membership provider for live site then we can share `core` db . And i understand we have set of defined configuration needed to set up each server role.

But my question is if we are using sitecore for the  static site creation for which the analytics tracking and login are not needed then do we still need this `core` database?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified version of Sitecore but as of Sitecore 9.1, ​​The Content Delivery server role does not require the Core database when the Sitecore security membership provider is not used.​​

As specified in release notes for this version -> https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/91/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2091%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes

Comment: Thats great ! it clarifies me with the purpose why we use core DB and ,though, i am looking for the version 8.x .